# How to make non-interactive Maple exit on assertion failure?

Tags: assert, exit-code, maple

My `t.ms` file contains:

```
interface(prettyprint=0): kernelopts(assertlevel=1):
ASSERT(1<1):
ASSERT(2<2):
```

When I run:

```
maple -q t.ms; echo $?
```

I get:

```
Error, assertion failed
Error, assertion failed
0
```

When I run:

```
maple -e 2 -q t.ms; echo $?
```

I get:

```
Error, assertion failed
0
```

I want to get:

```
Error, assertion failed
4
```

That is, I want Maple to exit with a nonzero exit status upon the first failing assertion. (I don't care if the exit code is 1 or anything else as long as it's nonzero. I've got the number 4 from the [documentation](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=maple), related to *errorbreak*) How do I get that?

Comment: An exit code of `1` means maple failed to initialize/start up. Why do you want to use that? Exit codes are to report to the OS to determine *why* maple closed. In your example, maple is running and closing correctly. [Looks like you can return your own with `quit(n)`, `done(n)`, or `stop(n)`, though.](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=maple)

Comment: You can get maple to exit upon the first uncaught error (caused in this case by the first failed assertion) by using the `-e 2` option.

Comment: @acer: Thanks for `-e 2`. It indeed causes an early exit, but with a 0 exit code. I've updated my question to reflect that. How do I get an early exit with a nonzero exit code?

Comment: @admdrew: I don't care about the actual exit code, as long as it's nonzero. The reason I want nonzero is so that the calling process can easily distinguish whether Maple has successfully run the commands end-to-end (0 exit code), or there was any failure (nonzero exit code) including an assertion failure.

Comment: @pts Understood. Unfortunately, though, it seems likely that you're going to need to force a `quit(n)` to get the code you want, as an assertion failure is not analogous to an *application* failure.

Comment: To the downvoters: what's wrong with this question? Is it offtopic? Is it unclear what I need or difficult to understand? I'd like to improve it as much as possible, to make it useful for both myself and the community, and to make it easy to answer (with little effort) for those who know the answer.

Comment: @admdrew: Should I define my own `ASSERT` function then, which will call `quit(4)`? How do I do that?

Comment: @pts Do you need an `ASSERT`? Can you `try`/`catch` your conditions instead, and fire a `quit(4)` on failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation doesn't make it very clear that one must use,

```
`quit`(n)
```

with name-quotes.

```
interface(prettyprint=0):

handler:=proc(e::uneval)
  local failed;
  printf("entered\n"); # remove this when satisfied
  failed:=false;
  try
    if evalb(eval(e)) <> true then
      error;
    end if;;
  catch:
    failed:=true;
    printf("Error, assertion failed\n");
  finally;
    if failed then
       `quit`(5);
    end if;
  end try;
  true;
end proc:

ASSERT( handler( 1<1 )):
ASSERT( handler( 2<2 )):
```

Now, saving this as file `uh.mpl` then using Maple 18.01 for Linux I see,

```
$ maple18.01 -q -A 2 ~/uh.mpl ; echo $?
entered
Error, assertion failed
5
```

And if run without the `-A 2` then it doesn't run the asserted checks.

[edited] Here below is a slight modification, to process additional arguments as part of the printing.

```
handler:=proc(e::uneval)
  local failed;
  printf("entered\n"); # remove this when satisfied
  failed:=false;
  try
    if evalb(eval(e)) <> true then
      error;
    end if;;
  catch:
  failed:=true;
  printf("Error, assertion failed, %q\n", _rest);
  finally;
  if failed then
     `quit`(5);
  end if;
  end try;
  true;
end proc:
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Can you please add more arguments to `handler` to display a custom error message, similar to what `ASSERT(1<1, (2, 3, [4, 5], "foo"))` displays?

Comment: I made a revision, for extra arguments.